# Converting to PDO issue

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am attemping to convert MySQLi code to PDO. `class DB` has the following code:

```
class DB {
    private static $instance;
    private $conn;

    private function __construct(array $dbOptions){
            $this->conn = @ new conn(   $dbOptions['db_host'],
                                    $dbOptions['db_user'],
                                    $dbOptions['db_pass'],
                                    $dbOptions['db_name'] );

        if (conn_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception('Database error.');
        }

        $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
    }


    public static function init(array $dbOptions){
        if(self::$instance instanceof self){
            return false;
        }

        self::$instance = new self($dbOptions);
    }

    public static function getconnObject(){
        return self::$instance->conn;
    }

    public static function query($q){
        return self::$instance->conn->query($q);
    }
```

**Here I only changed the constructor to:**

```
    private function __construct(array $dbOptions){
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbOptions['db_host']};dbname={$dbOptions['db_name']};charset=utf8", $dbOptions['db_user'], $dbOptions['db_pass']);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

**And here I only changed the `query($q)` function to:**

```
public static function query($q, $paramArray=array()){

    $stmt = self::$instance->conn->prepare($q);
    foreach ($paramArray as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    self::$instance = $stmt;
    return  $stmt;
}
```

So far so good. I am now binding my parameters and preparing the sql statment. Now another class `ChatUser` has the following code (before me changing it):

```
    DB::query("
        INSERT INTO webchat_users (name, gravatar)
        VALUES (
            '".DB::esc($this->name)."',
            '".DB::esc($this->gravatar)."'
    )");

    return DB::getconnObject();
```

which I changed to:

```
    $paramArray = array(
         ":name" => $this->name,
         ":gravatar" => $this->gravatar
    );

    DB::query("
        INSERT INTO webchat_users (name, gravatar)
        VALUES (:name, :gravatar)", $paramArray);

    return DB::getconnObject();
```

**QUESTION / PROBLEM:** My code is failing at `return DB::getconnObject();` in the changed code. I can't seem to figure out why.

I am getting the following errors in the error_log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
>   in DB.class.php on line 41 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   rowCount() on a non-object in Chat.class.php on line 31

Line 41 of DB.class.php is the line: `$stmt = self::$instance->conn->prepare($q);` in the previous code above

Line 31 of Chat.class.php is the line: `if($user->save()->rowCount() != 1){`
where `$user->save()` obtains the value returned by `return DB::getconnObject();`

I just can't understand what is causing the error.

ORIGINAL CODE SOURCE: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/

Comment: I'm thinking now that `$conn` could be `null`, and that would happen if the constructor wasn't called, and for that to happen I'm thinking the `init()` function might not have been called. It would be helpful to see the whole workflow, how you're getting the instance, where you're calling `init()` and then where you're referring to `$conn`.

Comment: @rid the original code is in the source link at the bottom of the question. What I am also not understanding is why `getconnObject()` even exists, when I might just be able to do `return DB::query("...")` without the extra line.

Comment: This requires debugging. The next step would be to see if you do indeed have an `$instance` and a `$conn` inside it. I would probably start by adding a `var_dump(self::$instance)` and `var_dump(self::$instance->conn)` in `query()` and see what they show.

Comment: @rid thanks for the feedback, I'll try to see if I manage something. If I find the answer, I'll post it here just in case you were curious as to what the problem was :)